# Key usage in Hyperledger Fabric node TLS Certificates

Tags: ssl, hyperledger-fabric, tls1.2, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am generating certificates in Hyperledger Fabric using the Fabric CA. I am passing a self-signed certificate as the root certificate for both enrollment and TLS certificate issuance in HLF. It is for testing purpose and so same Fabric CA (single root certificate) is used to issue enrollment and TLS certificates. The root certificate has following `Key Usages`:

```
X509v3 Key Usage: critical
    Digital Signature, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
    TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
```

In the node enrollment certificate, I have following `Key Usages`:

```
X509v3 Key Usage: critical
    Digital Signature
```

Now, for TLS certificate I run the `fabric-ca-client enroll` command and pass `--enrollment.profile tls` as one the arguments to the call. When I decode the node TLS PEM certificate, I get the following `Key Usages`:

```
X509v3 Key Usage: critical
    Digital Signature, Key Encipherment, Key Agreement
X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
    TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
```

Now, I was referring one RFC [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5480) to identify the **Elliptic Curve Cryptography Subject Public Key Information**. In section-3, I read that `Key Encipherment` is not valid key usage extension for elliptic curve certificates. Through some more research, I also found that, `Key Encipherment` is used for symmetric key encryption (please correct me if I am wrong).

Now, my questions are:

1. Why is Fabric CA adding `Key Encipherment` as a key usage in the node TLS certificate if it is not according to the ECC RFC standards?
2. How does actually TLS communication happen in case of elliptic curve certificates and keys?

Comment: I would highly recommend asking this question on the mailing list, you are much more likely to get one of our crypto experts who implemented this (and have deep technical backgrounds in it) to answer your question: https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/fabric/topics

Answer (score 1):

Fabric CA currently supports issuing both EC and RSA certificates.  The default `tls` profile sets the key usages / extended key usages required for both.

If you want to limit the usages, you can edit the `tls` signing profile section in `fabric-ca-server-config.yaml`:

```
signing:
    default:
      usage:
        - digital signature
      expiry: 8760h
    profiles:
      ca:
         usage:
           - cert sign
           - crl sign
         expiry: 43800h
         caconstraint:
           isca: true
           maxpathlen: 0
      tls:
         usage:
            - signing
            - server auth
            - client auth
         expiry: 8760h
```

Fabric CA only checks to make sure that the root cert has the CA constraint set too true.  It does not limit the key usages for the certs it signs to it's own extensions (this is not technical required).  If consumers of certificates wish to enforce usage constraints for the certificate based on the issuer as well, they do that themselves.  `openssl` for example makes sure that a CA was allowed to sign certificates with the key usage it requires.  It does not prohibit other extension though.

Comment: I understood. Let's say if we go by the RFC, is it a best practice to rely on users to create node certificate following EC standards, or is it good enough to develop a CA service which will guarantee that those standards are followed. This question occurs mainly because node TLS certificates cannot be used for `Key Encirpherment` theoretically. However, I cannot think of a negative scenario in HLF - which will put the network at a threat if node TLS certificate has that Key Usage.

Comment: There's no issue here.  We really wanted separate profiles for TLS and Enrollment to handle separation of concerns such that the same cert was not used for both signing and TLS.